# Using in-memory filesystem in `pyarrow` tests

Tags: python, filesystems, parquet, pyarrow

I have some `pyarrow` Parquet dataset writing code. I want to have an integration test that ensures the file is written correctly. I'd like to do that by writing a small example data chunk to an in-memory filesystem. However, I'm struggling to find a `pyarrow`-compatible in-memory filesystem interface for Python.

You'll find a snippet of code that has a `filesystem` variable in it below. I'd like to replace the `filesystem` variable with an in-memory filesystem that I can later inspect in integration tests programmatically.

```py
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
pq.write_to_dataset(
        score_table,
        root_path=AWS_ZEBRA_OUTPUT_S3_PREFIX,
        filesystem=filesystem,
        partition_cols=[
            EQF_SNAPSHOT_YEAR_PARTITION,
            EQF_SNAPSHOT_MONTH_PARTITION,
            EQF_SNAPSHOT_DAY_PARTITION,
            ZEBRA_COMPUTATION_TIMESTAMP
        ]
    )
```

Comment: Perhaps temporary files can help - would still end up on disk though: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Comment: Thanks @Jay. I'd like to avoid creating temporary files for integration tests, as this introduces an external system dependency and increases the risk of tests being flaky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I've manually implemented an instance of the `pyarrow.FileSystem` ABC. It seems that using `mock` for testing purposes fails, as `pyarrow` (not in the most Pythonic way) checks for the type of the `filesystem` parameter passed to `write_to_dataset`: https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/5e201fed061f2a95e66889fa527ae8ef547e9618/python/pyarrow/filesystem.py#L383. I suggest to change the logic in this method to not check for types explicitly (even `isinstance` would be preferable!) to allow for easier testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an in-memory file object to `write_to_dataset` if `filesystem` is `None`.

So your call might become:

```
from io import BytesIO
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

with BytesIO() as f:
    pq.write_to_dataset(
        score_table,
        root_path=f,
        filesystem=None,
        partition_cols=[
            EQF_SNAPSHOT_YEAR_PARTITION,
            EQF_SNAPSHOT_MONTH_PARTITION,
            EQF_SNAPSHOT_DAY_PARTITION,
            ZEBRA_COMPUTATION_TIMESTAMP
        ]
    )
```

Relevant lines from pyarrow source:

```
def resolve_filesystem_and_path(where, filesystem=None):
    """
    Return filesystem from path which could be an HDFS URI, a local URI,
    or a plain filesystem path.
    """
    if not _is_path_like(where):
        if filesystem is not None:
            raise ValueError("filesystem passed but where is file-like, so"
                             " there is nothing to open with filesystem.")
        return filesystem, where
```

https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/207b3507be82e92ebf29ec7d6d3b0bb86091c09a/python/pyarrow/filesystem.py#L402-L411

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out - it looks promising! I'll update you once I've tried.

Comment: Jay, this does not seem to work. `pyarrow` complains about `None` object not having attributes it expects from `filesystem`. Which `pyarrow` version have you tested this with?

Comment: Can you please open a JIRA issue with Apache Arrow if you are having some trouble?